# how can we get the array id of selected checkbox in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to get the array id of selected checkbox but unable to get the array. I need the array in format of `["302740", "42006", "331497"]`

here it is my app.js

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {     

    $scope.categories = [ {"tid":"302740","name":"2 BE 3"},{"tid":"42006","name":"A Line"},{"tid":"331497","name":"Activa"} ];
    $scope.brandlist = [];

    $scope.get = function (val) {
        console.log(val);

        var idx = $scope.brandlist.indexOf(val);

        if (idx > -1) 
            $scope.brandlist.splice(idx, 1);                
        else 
            $scope.brandlist.push(val);

        console.log($scope.brandlist);        
        // should come like selected array ["302740", "42006", "331497"] 
    }

}
```

and here it is the html

```html
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <span ng-repeat="(key,val) in categories">
        <label class="checkbox" for="{{key.tid}}">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-change="get(val.tid)" ng-model="brandlist[val.tid]" ng-checked="brandlist.indexOf(val.tid) > -1" name="group" id="{{val.tid}}" />
            {{val.name}}         
        </label>
    </span>
</div>
```

[plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/PQvQ2/1294/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying this

```
$scope.categories = [ {"tid":"302740","name":"2 BE 3"},{"tid":"42006","name":"A Line"},{"tid":"331497","name":"Activa"} ];

$scope.selecetedCategories = function toggleSelection(category){
   var idx = $scope.selectedCategories.indexOf(category);
      if(idx > -1){
        $scope.selecetedCategories.splice(idx,1);
      }
      else{
        $scope.selecetedCategories.push(category);
      }
};
```

You can print the selected categories like this

```
console.log($scope.selecetedCategorie);
```

And your html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedCategories"
 value="{{category}}" ng-checked="selectedCategories.indexOf(category) >
 -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(category)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about manipulating the source array, you can use that to maintain the state.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <span ng-repeat="(key,val) in categories">
        <label class="checkbox" for="{{key.tid}}">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="val.checked" name="group" id="{{val.tid}}" />
            {{val.name}}         
        </label>
    </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.categories = [ {"tid":"302740","name":"2 BE 3"},{"tid":"42006","name":"A Line"},{"tid":"331497","name":"Activa"} ];

// get the selected categories
var selectedCategories = $scope.categories.filter(function(itm) {
   return itm.checked;
});
```